# How to start jetty on port 80 as root from embedded jetty?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, setuid

I am trying to start the https port 443 as root then downgrade to non-root user using embedded jetty. I gone through the 
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setting-port80-access.html#configuring-jetty-setuid-feature 
but didn't get any solution how to do it from java program.

This is the embedded jetty code :

```
package com.jetty.startup;

import java.io.File;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

import org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter;
import org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JettyJasperInitializer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.*;

/**
 * Handles Webapp server's serviice
 * 
 * 
 */
class MyServer {
   private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class);

   private static Server server;
   private String jettyHome;

   /**
    * Creates an instance of {@link MyServer}
    * 
    * @param jettyHome
    *            jetty home path
    */
    public MyServer(String jettyHome) {
       this.jettyHome = jettyHome;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes Webapp server:
     * 
     */
    public Server init() throws Exception {
      server = new Server();

      int httpsPort = 443;

      String keyStoreFile = "/home/jetty/webserver/etc/keystore";
      String keyStorePassword = "secret";
      String keyManagerPassword = "secret";
      String trustStorePassword = "secret";

     SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
     sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(keyStoreFile);
     sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreType("JKS");
     sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(keyStorePassword);
     sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(keyManagerPassword);

     SetUIDListener set = new SetUIDListener();
     set.setStartServerAsPrivileged(true);
     set.setUsername("jetty");
     set.setGroupname("jetty");
     set.setUmask(002);

     server.addLifeCycleListener(set);

     HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
     httpConfiguration.setSecurePort(httpsPort);
     httpConfiguration.setSecureScheme("https");
     httpConfiguration.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

     ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(server, 
                    new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
                    new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfiguration));
     serverConnector.setPort(httpsPort);

     server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { serverConnector });

     WebAppContext myContext = new WebAppContext();
     myContext.setContextPath("/myapp");
     myContext.setWar(jettyHome + "/webapps/myapp/");
     myContext.setDefaultsDescriptor(jettyHome + "/etc/webdefault.xml");
     File overrideFile = new File(jettyHome
            + "/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/generated-web.xml");
     if (overrideFile.exists()) {
        myContext.setOverrideDescriptor(jettyHome
                + "/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/generated-web.xml");
     }

     server.setHandler(myContext);

     JettyJasperInitializer sci = new JettyJasperInitializer();
     ServletContainerInitializersStarter sciStarter = 
        new ServletContainerInitializersStarter(myContext);
     ContainerInitializer initializer = new ContainerInitializer(sci, null);
     List<ContainerInitializer> initializers = new ArrayList<>();
     initializers.add(initializer);

     myContext.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.containerInitializers", initializers);
     myContext.addBean(sciStarter, true);

     ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
     contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[] { myContext });

     server.setHandler(contexts);
     return server;
}

 public static void main(String args[]) {
        String jetty_home = "/home/jetty/webServer";
        MyServer myServer = new MyServer(jetty_home);
        try {
            server = myServer.init();
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception excp) {
        }
 }
}
```

As for the libsetuid-linux.so I've already created the native version of it using `mvn clean install` from the `jetty-setuid` project.

If `httpsPort = 2400` then this is the log file details:

**Log**

```
2016-02-11 15:36:16.413:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2424ms  
2016-02-11 15:36:16.593:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting umask=02
2016-02-11 15:36:16.603:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Opened         ServerConnector@b96fde{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:2400}  
2016-02-11 15:36:16.603:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting GID=504  
2016-02-11 15:36:16.676:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting UID=504  
2016-02-11 15:36:16.680:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.7.v20160115
```

whereas when `httpsPort = 443` this is how the log file looks:

**Log**

```
2016-02-11 15:37:35.049:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2199ms  
2016-02-11 15:37:35.228:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting umask=02
```

Nothing happens after this on the log and also the webapp isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally I was able to achieve what I'd asked in the above question by creating a libsetuid-linux.so for 32-bit, the one that's supplied with jetty-9.3.7 is for 64-bit.

How I created the 32-bit libsetuid-linux.so?

This link helped http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setting-port80-access.html
Point number 5 to be precise

But unfortunately the link for jetty-setuid project isn't working anymore.

Also, the `sudo` had to be done with `sudo -E`.

Answer (score 1):

This is ultimately a OS permissions issue, and you'll need a way to work around that.

> This means any solution you come up with will also be OS specific

One example is to use the [`jetty-setuid-java`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-setuid-java%22) artifact, and appropriate [`jetty-setuid-native`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-setuid-native%22) library to accomplish this.

> Make sure you fully understand how setuid functions on your desired OS before starting this effort

As for enabling the jetty setuid specific pieces, you can either use the [`XmlConfiguration`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/xml/XmlConfiguration.html) to inject the appropriate lifecycle listener into your `Server`, or you can do it entirely in code.

See the Jetty Distribution's [`etc/jetty-setuid.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.7.v20160115/jetty-distribution/src/main/resources/etc/jetty-setuid.xml) for help.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
           "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<!-- ================================================================ -->
<!-- Configure the Jetty SetUIDListener                                -->
<!-- ================================================================ -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <Call name="addLifeCycleListener">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener">
        <Set name="startServerAsPrivileged">false</Set>
        <Set name="umaskOctal">002</Set>
        <Set name="username">jetty</Set>
        <Set name="groupname">jetty</Set>
        <!-- uncomment to change the limits on number of open file descriptors for root -->
        <!--
        <Call name="setRLimitNoFiles">
          <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.RLimit">
              <Set name="soft">20000</Set>
              <Set name="hard">40000</Set>
            </New>
          </Arg>
        </Call>
        -->
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

Comment: I've submitted the code, please take a look and help me to make it work.